# Firebase hosting not showing my app content

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am currently trying to deploy my angular app to firebase. My index.html keeps getting overwritten when I deploy the app and the welcome modal shows up instead of my app content. I checked all the questions related to this topic but none of the answers provided helped me.

This is what I have tried so far:

- selecting "NO" when asked `File dist/index.html already exists. Overwrite? (y/N) N`
- replacing index.html with my own index.html
- in similar questions users suggested to switch to incognito mode in Chrome or to clear cache - didn't work either
- configure my base href in project's index.html and add my firebase project
  `< base href="https://["YOUR FIREBASE PROJECT NAME"].firebaseapp.com/">`
- deleting my dist folder and re-running `ng build --prod`and then `firebase init` and `firebase deploy`

Also when I redo the last step, firebase doesn't ask whether it should replace index.html it just replaces it. 
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Should I maybe switch to another hosting provider like Heroku instead?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There is no need to switch to another hosting provider, Firebase hosting is excellent. Can you please verify, before you ` firebase deploy --only hosting` that in your whole folder where you running your command is not any other index.html, just that one that you have from angular?

Comment: I had two index.html. After deleting the one created from firebase I got a 'Page not found error' and a message displaying that my index.html could not be found. I also checked my firebase.json to make sure it refers to that file.

Comment: It worked now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention that you are:

> deleting my `dist` folder and re-running `ng build --prod` and then **`firebase init`** and `firebase deploy`

You should not run `firebase init` several times. This is the command used to create your Firebase project and it should be called only once.

So, to deploy a new version of your app, you need to put under the `dist` folder of your Firebase project, the result of your build (`ng build --prod`), replacing any file/directory that is there (in particular the default Firebase `index.html` file created by `firebase init`), and then call `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only hosting`.

Between each deployment, you **don't need to delete the `dist` folder**. Just **delete its content** and replace it by the files/directories that were generated by your build process.

---

Note that I wrote "under the `dist` folder of your Firebase project" because your answer to the "What do you want to use as your public folder?" question is `dist`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it worked now! :)  I also had to select the dist/<MYPROJECT> folder insted of dist folder.

Comment: well worked for me too :)